# Avoid FOUT issue seen on Headless website

Tags: html, css, reactjs, fonts, shopify

[image]My website uses React, shopify and currently I am trying load fonts on my website which are uploaded on the netlify server(same as where the website is hosted). However I can see a very visible FOUT when the website is loaded. Have used the below font load best practices :

- using preload when trying to access the fonts
- using font-display: swap
- using fallback fonts

I would appreciate some help to avoid the FOUT seen on the website

Comment: Are you observing this FOUT on every page load? If so, are caching headers correctly set, so that the browser can cache the font files?

Comment: yes, the FOUT is seen on every pageload. Could you please provide more details about the caching headers.

Currently when i check the response headers on clicking the font in the networks tab i get the below output

Age: 164940
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31557600
CF-Cache-Status: HIT
CF-RAY: 77548f997c9ef484-BOM
Content-Length: 21424
Content-Type: font/woff2

Comment: That looks ok. Can you verify in the network tab whether a) browser cache is enabled, b) the font file is loaded from cache?

Comment: Actually it is an issue which multiple clients have reported, so my browser settings would not matter much i guess :)

Comment: The point is to verify whether your browser is using its cache. If not, something might be wrong with the Caching headers. The `max-age` you sent allows a year of caching. So any page should not at all need to transfer the font file over the wire, you should not have a FOUT. Can you share your HTML of how the font is referenced?

Comment: Updated the post to show how the fonts are being called.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250216/discussion-between-apurva-t-and-andy).

Answer (score 3):

`font-display: swap` doesn't prevent FOUT. Quite opposite - often it can cause it.

#### `font-display: optional` Can Solve FOIT And FOUT

This option basically makes web fonts optional, or to put differently, if the font isn’t there by the time the page needs it, then it’s up to the browser to never swap it.

But this is not the greatest solution because the web font won't load sometimes. What I would do is:

- Keep `font-display: swap` but improve font style matching with the fallback font [You can use font style matcher for that](https://meowni.ca/font-style-matcher/)
- Optimize font -> remove unused glyphs and weights
- Serve font from the same origin as a website is served
- If font is served from 3rd party service due to legal reasons you can cache it using Service Workers.

You might also don't care as this is a minor performance issue (usually).

Comment: Thankyou for you answer. 
- font-display: optional did not help. With this property set the web font did not load at all.
- Even if i manage to find best matching style configuration for the fallback font using font matcher, how would i set it ? as common font styling is normally applied to the main and fallback font.
- Serve font from the same origin as a website is served - this we already have on our site.
- Optimize font -> remove unused glyphs and weights - will try this and check if it helps

Comment: If the font won't be fetched in 100ms then it won't load at all. This is the rule for optional font display. If you scroll down on the linked page you will notice that there is a link to another article, that describes the technique: https://helenvholmes.com/writing/type-is-your-right/

Comment: The problem here is that every time I load the page the change from fallback font to web font is visible. Ideally the shift should have been visible only on first load and subsequent page loads should not see the shift.